# SQL only check column if its not null

Tags: mysql, sql

Really hard to explain but here goes

I have a query that checks a number of fields, but on one of them makeCall I need to display it if its null, but if its not null then I need to check that the date is = to today, if it is display, if its not don't.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    SELECT
        renewaldate,
        DATEDIFF(renewaldate, CURDATE()) AS DaysUntilRenewalDate,
        orders.*, customers.*
    FROM
        orders
    JOIN customers ON orders.CustomerNumber = customers.CustomerNumber
    WHERE 
    RenewalDate < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 23 DAY)
    AND RenewalDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)
    AND IF MakeCall IS NOT NULL THEN WHERE ITS = TO TODAY?
    ORDER BY
        RenewalDate
```

The  "AND IF MakeCall IS NOT NULL THEN WHERE ITS = TO TODAY?" is where it would go

Comment: Something like ... AND (MakeCall IS NULL OR MakeCall  = today)...

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I didn't think of something simple like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND (MakeCall IS NULL OR MakeCall = today)
```

As suggested by [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh)